# How to do an initial setup of slapd OLC with ldapmodify

Tags: linux, openldap

I've run into sort of a deadlock setting up an LDAP server on CentOS.
I use the on-line configuration files under /etc/openldap/slapd.d
The documentation tells you not to modify those files by hand, and the files are checksummed.
But I cannot use ldapmodify, because I can't log in (simple bind) - and I can't log in because I can't set a password for the user - and I can't set a password for the user because I can't use ldapmodify, because I can't log in, because I can't set a password, because ....

I could of course set it up by editing the files directly - and I have done it, and it works.
But it just bugs me, that I can't find a way to do it "properly".

Comment: I edit those files frequently *in extremis.* I've never read that they are checksummed. They can't be or this would fail. In this situation I don't see that you had any choice.

Comment: There is a comment at the top of the file

# AUTO-GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT!! Use ldapmodify.
# CRC32 3a7e5612

The slapd server throws a warnig upon start - but nothing "bad" happens. BTW: Ubuntu asks you for a password on installing the slapd package... guess I'm gonna check the post-execution-files at some point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Ubuntu (Debian Packages)

Ubuntu and maybe other distributions with debian packages try to be super smart and set up everything for you - which really becomes a problem when you want to do a non-interactive installation, because debconf will set random admin-passwords and also configure the base-DN according to your machine name. You might be able to guess the base-DN - but you can't guess the password, and as it is deleted from the debconf-DB after installation you can not read it out.

You can however configure the passwords and DN **before** you install the package:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
sudo debconf-set-selections <<EOF
slapd slapd/internal/generated_adminpw password changeme
slapd slapd/password2 password changeme
slapd slapd/internal/adminpw password changeme
slapd slapd/password1 password changeme
slapd slapd/domain string example.com
slapd shared/organization string example.com
EOF

sudo apt-get install -y slapd ldap-utils
```

Be **very** careful with your spaces here: putting two spaces before the password will set the password to __changeme_ (that is: (*blankspace*)changeme)

Thanks to  [OpenStackPro](http://openstack.prov12n.com/quiet-or-unattended-installing-openldap-on-ubuntu-14-04/) for showing how to configure the selections

You can test your setup with

```
ldapsearch -x -D "cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com" -w "changeme"
```

Which should output in something like

```
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <> (default) with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 32 No such object

# numResponses: 1
```

This means, there is nothing in your LDAP-Database (yet), but at least you were able to log in :-)

If you get something like

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

you need to double check your admin-DN and password. You can check your admin-DN with

```
sudo slapcat -n0 | grep olcRootDN
```

## CentOS 6.6 (and most likely RedHat, Fedora etc.)

Install the packages

```
sudo yum -y install openldap openldap-servers openldap-clients
```

First get a password-hash with

```
slappasswd -s changeme
```

Be aware that the CentOS-package uses *my-domain.com* instead of *example.com*, so you might need to adapt the commands accordingly.

Create an initial ldif, in a file like *init.ldif*:

```
dn: dc=my-domain,dc=com
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: my-domain.com
dc: my-domain

dn: cn=admin,dc=my-domain,dc=com
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
userPassword: {SSHA}rX8oWGKW6B7mKY+nUJhrv4g1pPH5KtQg
```

To write this config to your LDAP use:

```
sudo slapadd -F /etc/openldap/slapd.d -b "cn=config" -l init.ldif
```

Again, You can test your setup with

```
ldapsearch -x -D "cn=admin,dc=my-domain,dc=com" -w "changeme"
```

(see above at "Ubuntu")

Comment: Could you elaborate why one needs to set the password on 4 debconf properties? I tried setting it on password1 and password2 (I guess for confirmation) and it works. Just asking in case I'm missing something.