# LDAP Client installation using ansible

Tags: ansible, ldap

We need to install LDAP client over 156 machines. So we want to use ansible to complete this task.

```
apt-get install ldap-utils libpam-ldapd libnss-ldapd nscd
```

But when we install it asked lot of question in response (popup box) and we are facing issue how we can handle those response in playbook.

I have used `expect` module but it was working well when we see question/response on screen not in popup box like below:

```
- name: run command to install rubyencoder
    expect:
      chdir: /home/ubuntu/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin
      command: /home/ubuntu/rubyencoder-evaluation/bin/rubyencoder
      responses:
        '.*Press return key to continue.*': ""
        '.*type \"I AGREE\".*': "I AGREE"
        '.*Your RubyEncoder profile e-mail.*': "abc@xyz.com"
        '.*Your RubyEncoder profile password.*': ""
```

Above config handle response properly but same method is not working in ldap client installation.

I am using below playbook:

```
---
- hosts: test1
  become: true
#  remote_user: dagar
#  sudo: yes
  tasks:
  - name: install ldap client packages
    expect:
     command: apt-get install ldap-utils libpam-ldapd libnss-ldapd nscd
     responses:
      '.*Do you want to continue?.*': ""
      '.*LDAP server URI.*': "Ok"
      '.*LDAP server search base.*': "Ok"
      '.*Name servives to configure.*': "Ok"
      '.*Restart services during package upgrades without asking?.*': "No"
      '.*Services to restart to make them use the new libraries.*': "Ok"
```

Can anybody please help me on above issue.

Any help or guidance will be appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "is not working" mean in this case? It hangs? It provides the wrong input? It reboots your computer? You have failed to include one shred of log output that might be able to help anyone to help you

Comment: Don't fire `apt-get` commands with shell. Use the [`apt` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_module.html) (non-interactive by default). The questions you answer when installing interactively are basically creating config files or enabling services by default. Just make sure you do the same thing in your playbook by pushing a [template file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) and/or enabling the service correctly (e.g. with [`systemd` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/systemd_module.html))

Comment: @mdaniel: It seems obvious to me what "is not working" means.  He does not know how to automate answering the questions.

Answer (score 0):

This accepted answer may help: [How to do an initial setup of slapd OLC with ldapmodify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28937889/how-to-do-an-initial-setup-of-slapd-olc-with-ldapmodify/29277856#29277856)

It uses slapd and a heredoc to define the answers for debconf-set-selections to consume.

Answer (score 0):

I run a one line command to join nodes to ldap (assuming the packages are installed and relevant services started. I use nslcd)

```sh
authconfig --enableldapauth --ldapserver="ldapserver.example.com" --ldapbasedn="dc=example,dc=com" --update
```

So Ansible method would be:

```yaml
- name: This command will join a node to an LDAP server
  ansible.builtin.shell:
    cmd: authconfig --enableldapauth --ldapserver="ldapserver.example.com" --ldapbasedn="dc=example,dc=com" --update
```

That *should* also update /etc/nsswitch.conf, but if not, you can always replace the file with ansible

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure how to do this with only ansible, but since you are already using expect for automating script responses you could use something like autohotkeys or sikuli to answer popups. You could have ansible run your expect script to answer the scripted responses and run the autohotkeys script to answer the popup. Or perhaps you can just modify whatever script you are running for the install in order to not make a popup.

You can see more info:

https://github.com/sikuli/sikuli
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm